How to list devices connected in AP_IF mode(esp32, micropython)
i want to list data of connected devices to my esp32 s3 AP
like device name
rssi
mac address
ip address
and anothers data
i used wlan.status('stations')
but it just return mac address
is there any way?
esp32 s3 and micropython v1.23
